# Hierachy organisational methodology in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm just getting into Unity, so I do not know if my system of organisation will have any negative consequences.

I intend to store my project files and assets under an assets directory, then into scripts and such, as is commonplace. For the hierarchy I intend to have a top level empty object titled something like "Hierarchy", under which all objects will be children.

I am also thinking that I will further subdivide into logical and physical objects, putting objects that do not have components on them but have a physical space in the game (not including transforms) under the former, and anything with a physical presence under the latter (lights, player etc).

The main reason is so that I know where to look, based on functionality. I can also use alt-click to close all objects at once. I find this helpful for navigating the hierarchy.

Is this a bad plan?

Comment: This is likely to come down to opinion and preference. However, I would advise against the practice of storing assets in subfolders by asset type (eg. scripts, sounds). In practice, someone working on a character will need to interact with textures, materials, meshes, animations, effects, scripts, and sounds — but not every texture etc, just the ones used by that character. This leads to a lot of redundant folder navigation. I find it much easier to divide assets by feature, rather than asset type (and the project view has filters in case you ever do need to look at all scripts/etc as a group)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the scene hierarchy, it's not a good idea. The scene hierarchy is meant to be designed in such a way that all objects that need to move together/are attached to each other should be placed as children of a parent game object.

For example, in a car object, the body and wheels are placed together under a parent "Car" object, since they generally move and rotate together in a real-life car. This set up allows the wheels to move and rotate in the same direction as the body when they aren't steered, but when they are an offset rotation is applied. The wheel still moves and rotates with the body, but it has some offset local rotation/position which is also added to it's world position and rotation.

You can also use parent and child Transforms to group objects for easy debugging like @SanSolo said, but only if you are sure that you won't change the Transform of the parent container in *any* way.

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchy, as Evil Tak said, is meant to give a semantic organization to your gameobjects such as the car of the other answer is all contained in a root node. Also you have to consider that transofmrations applied to a gameObject reflects to children too.

That is a fact. But then you have to consider that heirarchy is fully customizable so if for your needs is best to separate physical from logical entities, do it, just keep in mind the above.

Keep in mind also just one thing, the [execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) and rendering order. Without [personalization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html), scripts are executed from top to bottom in the hierarchy (all `Awake()` functions in order top-bottom; all `Start()` functions in order top-bottom, and so on) and so rendering is performed hierarchy wise in the same order.

If you have this clear in mind you can organise your hierarchy as you prefere.

Answer (score -1):

Hierarchy doesn't really matter in the "Hierarchy panel". Hierarchy is useful if you have a bunch of game objects,it would be wise to organize them. However there is a game object where hierarchy does matter. It's the `Canvas` game object. The `Canvas` is used to display pictures,text,buttons,etc. It's used for HUDs,menus and similar. If you place 2 images in it,the last image will be the one who will overlay all the previous images,in this case the previous image. And that's why hierarchy matters here.

Comment: Hierarchy most definitely ***does*** matter; If an object has any children in its hierarchy, any transform applied to the parent will *also* be applied to the children. If you had not meant for this to happen, it can lead to some major issues, especially if not caught early.